# Computing derivative of Riemann zeta efficiently

Tags: complex-analysis, computational-complexity, riemann-zeta

What is the most efficient way of computing derivative of Riemann zeta function?

If you let Mathematica to plot $\left|\zeta(1/2+i x)\right|$ say on interval $0<x<100$ it is very fast. But if you let it to plot $\left|\zeta'(1/2+i x)\right|$ it takes "ages" to finish.
I do not understand why this two things should be of different difficulty (computational complexity).

Any ideas how to implement better algorithm in Mathematica?

Comment: Within the critical strip, one can use something called the approximate functional equation to compute $\zeta(s)$. This is very fast, and is based on the functional equation. The functional equation for $\zeta'$ is a bit more complicated, so one cannot use the same "approximate functional equation" technique. It seems likely that Mathematics uses either a standard local approximation (compute a limit using values of $\zeta(s)$) or a Cauchy integral to evaluate the derivative. I'm not sure what Mathematica actually does.

Comment: I might add that a very fast computation of L-function derivatives is implemented within pari/gp. I didn't try to figure out how it works, as the code itself is very hard to understand. But perhaps there is an exposition somewhere of how they do it.

Comment: It is same slow also outside the critical strip, even for non-complex argument still slow. Can someone compare it with other mathematical software (sage, maple, mathlab...)?

Comment: @mixedmath What about using [this formula for $\eta(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms) everywhere and for all the derivatives ?

Comment: @reuns That's a good idea. And it's easy to implement. And it converges like... $1/\sqrt{n}$? Is that right?

Comment: @mixedmath It converges in $\mathcal{O}((2-\epsilon)^{-n})$ but the $\mathcal{O}$ constant is hard to estimate (it depends mainly on $\Im(s)$) that's why the (harder to implement) Chebyshev polynomials method is preferred.

Comment: @reuns Oh, how do you see that? I had naively thought that the central binomial coefficient would more fully counteract for the exponential $2^{-n}$ out front.